# How to match the 3 adjacent array elements when array size is different each time?

Tags: java

I have an array declaration like this:

```
private int number = 0;
private Block circles[];
```

Initializing the array like this:

```
number = Math.abs(random.nextInt(5)) + 4;
circles = new Block[number];
```

This array will have different size on initialization, that varies from 3 to 8.

Suppose array length is 5;

When I iterate through the array, I want to check,any of the three adjacent indices of the array contains same property/value.

that means, if either *0,1,2* or *1,2,3* or *2,3,4* indices contain same value, it should return true.

It should not check *4,0,1*.

From array size 3 to 7, how can I frame a general method to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try something, if yes please present the code?

Comment: We are not a free code-writing service. Attempt a solution yourself. If it doesn't work, feel free to post a question asking why.

Comment: How would you do it for a known fixed array length? Any reasonable implantation with a for loop would work for any length of array - Just iterate from zero to array length minus 3 and Check every 3 consecutive elements. You need to make your own attempt first before asking on SO

Comment: So stop your iteration when you reach the end of the array, something like `i < circles.length - 1` (assuming i is the middle index)

Comment: `random.nextInt(5)` returns an integer between 0 (inclusive) and 5(exclusive), why are you calling Math.abs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you require 3 contiguous the be the same, it seems reasonable that if there aren't at least 3 elements to check, the check is false.

In pseudo code:

- if the length of the array is less than 3 return `false`
- for each index from `0`, and always less than the length of array minus 2

  - save the tested attribute of the element at the current index
  - if the next 2 elements have the same value for their attribute return `true`
- return `false`

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over a sliding window:

```
public static boolean threeMatch(Block[] arr) {
    // Assume that arr is at least the size of 3:
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; ++i) {
        if (arr[i].equals(arr[i + 1]) && arr[i + 1].equals(arr[i + 2]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```